# PySide QApplication([]) segfaults, but only in non-interactive ipython session

Tags: python, qt, segmentation-fault, pyside

I read that an empty list as an argument for the QApplication should work (instead of sys.argv). However in my case it does work when running it in an interactive ipython shell, but executing it with ipython results in a segmentation fault.
Any idea why that happens? What makes the difference?

This works:

```
[jhennrich@tp-arch qt_test]$ ipython2
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jun 28 2016, 08:31:05) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from PySide.QtCore import *
   ...: from PySide.QtGui import *
   ...: 
   ...: app = QApplication([])
   ...: 
/home/jhennrich/.gtkrc-2.0:38: error: scanner: unterminated string constant

In [2]:
```

(I also tried it with more code, the application shows a window and stuff)

When executed as a script it doesnt work:

segfault1.py:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

app = QApplication([])
```

running it:

```
[jhennrich@tp-arch qt_test]$ ipython2 segfault1.py 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[jhennrich@tp-arch qt_test]$ ipython2
```

Comment: Try this: `app = QApplication([''])`.

Comment: That fixes it, thank you. Still I am curious why this doesnt happen in interactive ipython mode. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know the exact cause. I think it may have something to do with the widget style. I'm guessing you might not get any errors if you do `app = QCoreApplication([])`. Or if you do `QApplication.setStyle('fusion')` before creating a `QApplication`.

Comment: Using sys.argv in such cases is maybe the best solution.